# price table structure for multiple currency ecommerce website

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, e-commerce

I have developed a e-Commerce website in Codeigniter 2.0, MySQL integrated PayPal with USD as Default Currency. Now my client requested me to change the e-commerce to support multiple countries with their currencies. My Multi Currency doesn't convert the currency, But gonna fix the prices for each product for all currencies.. Yes it gonna be a big data entry work for my client, but it is the only option for my e-commerce website.

I have listed the currencies which are supported by PayPal. And stuck while creating the database for the e-commerce

I have 2 options for new table structure, but can't find which one will be the best.  Please consider **Products will be added as dynamically and new currencies may be added in future**.

**Option 1**

```
pro_id | USD_PRICE | EUR_PRICE | 
----------------------------------------
 1     |    2      |     1.5 
 2     |    2.5    |     2 
 3     |    10     |     8 
 4     |    2      |     1.5
```

**Option 2**

```
pro_id | price     | currency_code  | 
----------------------------------------
 1     |    2      |     USD 
 1     |    1.5    |     EUR 
 3     |    10     |     USD
 3     |    8      |     EUR
```

Answer (score 2):

this is how i would design the tables

```
product table
id, base amount, base currencyid

currency table
currencyid , description

forex table
currencyid, forexcurrencyid, forexrate, forex date

order table
productid, base amount, converted amount, currencyid, ....
```

Comment: thank you for you suggestion.. i will continue with my option 2 with your method